# Sorting observableArray with added item Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to get my observableArray to alphabetically sort with the addition of a new item to the list when clicking "sort". Can anyone shed some light on what i'm doing wrong here?

Thank you,

Jason

........................

https://jsfiddle.net/jaloomis111/tssLxbo0/

```
<input data-bind="value: inputName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" type="text"/>
<ul data-bind="foreach: myFamily"/>
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">add item</button>
<button data-bind="click: sortArray">sort array</button>

$(function(){

var data = [
    {name: 'Jason'}, 
    {name: 'Alexi'},
    {name: 'Gabi'}
]; 


viewModel = {
        inputName: ko.observable(""),
    myFamily : ko.observableArray(data),
    //addItem : function(){
      //this.myFamily.push({name: this.inputName()});
      //this.inputName("");
    //},
    addItem : function() {
            this.myFamily.push({name: this.inputName()});
    },

    removeItem : function(){
        this.myFamily.pop();
    },

    sortArray : function(){
       this.myFamily.sort(function (left, right) { 
            return left.name == right.name ? 0 : (left.name < right.name ? -1 : 1) 
       })
    },

};

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort function does not operate on the array that is passed it, but instead returns a new sorted version of the array. So to update your observable with the sorted result you need to set its contents to the sort result.

```
sortArray : function(){
    this.myFamily(this.myFamily().sort(function (left, right) { 
        return left.name.toLowerCase() == right.name.toLowerCase() ? 0 : (left.name.toLowerCase() < right.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1)
    }));
}
```

Currently your sort function is case sensitive, and I'm guessing you don't want that either. Capitalized names would always float up above non capitalized names.

**Edit: Whoops, you're using knockout's .sort() on the observable not javascript's sort on the array so you can disregard the first part of my answer. It's probably just the casing thing.**

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for taking the time to help me out Jason!